# How to make entry for chained models in polymorphic table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have below class

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :b 
  has_one :x, as: :xyz
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :c 
  has_one :x, as: :xyz
end
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  has_many :d 
  has_one :x, as: :xyz
end
class D < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c
  has_one :x, as: :xyz
end
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
  # level :integer
  belongs_to :xyz, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have created this polymorphic table to store a common attribute 'Level' (Common for all table). What I want to do is, In case class A is assigned level  =1, class A, B, C & D should also have level 1. In case only B is assigned level=2; B,C and D should have level=2.

I am not sure how to set these values..

Thanks.

Comment: what is the level? is level the field of `X`? then how do you assign the level?

Comment: Yes, level is field for X, user sets the value for it.  Updating it through nested_attributes in all model forms.